# ругулярка не работает в сафари, хотя в хроме все норм

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, safari

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться, что не так, горит(

ругулярка не работает в сафари, хотя в хроме все норм

Крашит приложение на сафари

```
/(?<!')\[([^";'[\]]+)]/g
```

Подскажите плз, как можно это обойти?

Comment: Потому что Safari не умеет look behind https://caniuse.com/js-regexp-lookbehind

Comment: Может есть какие-то варианты, как это обойти?

Comment: @ОлегШестаков `/(?:[^']|^)[([^";'[]]+)]/g` и забирать данные из 1й группы, вот эта часть очень странно выглядит `[([^";'[]]+)]` возможно стоит ее указать как `([^";'[]]+)`

Comment: @ipatev_nn , огонь, спасибо! теперь все работает, как надо